# sync Image data to the serve in mobile app, make application slow

Tags: ios, microsoft-sync-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Developing iPhone hybrid application using microsoft sync framework to sync the data to server 
When I use image data's in a table, it makes my app too slow and crashed after synchronization.
I have stored images base64 string in VarChar(max) format in db. 
Do I need to use another format or failed in any coding part which makes my app slow.

Comment: how big are the images you're loading? do you have enough memory to load them?

Comment: @JuneT its about 50 images with 50kb to 100kb in size